# justify for other elements rather then text

Tags: html, css

So I have a simple login prompt like this:

```
<form id="login">
  <legend>Login</legend>
  <span>
    <input type="text" value="Username">
    <input type="password" value="Password"><br>
    <input type="checkbox">Remember
    <a href="./login/vergeten.html">Forgot?</a>
    <a href="./login/Registreer.html">Register</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </span>
</form>
```

and the css:

```
#login {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tzc6Lpur/

What I would like is that the bottom items are stretched over the entire width of the element so that login button would be lined up to the right end of the password box. Something like text-align: justify; would to that for text but I can't find an easy way to do this. Ofcourse I could manually position the elements but that just seems to be a lot redundant code.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: You'll have to use flexbox here.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It is possible to use `text-align: justify;` for this although it does require some other changes to be made for it to work. https://jsfiddle.net/qyyjoo2v/

Comment: Check my answer I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: text-align:justify could be used for older browsers, flex will need some html adjustement too with justify-content:space-between. fiddle with text-align : https://jsfiddle.net/tzc6Lpur/3/ i can turn this into answers with both example text-align or flex if his is close to your needs  p.s. legend tag requires a fieldset tag

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be  to change your markup accordingly:

```
<form id="login">
  <legend>Login</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Username">
    <input type="password" value="Password"><br>
    <div class="flex-wrap">
        <label for="myCheckbox"><input name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox">Remember</label>
        <a href="./login/vergeten.html">Forgot?</a>
        <a href="./login/Registreer.html">Register</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and use the following CSS:

```
.flex-wrap{
   display:  flex; 
  flex-direction: row;   
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#login{
     float:right; //To mantain the form on the right of the screen
  }
```

Flex box is supported by all modern browsers, but if you need to support

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/hcktxgva/3/

Comment: Not proper, OP wants login button below the password field.

Answer (score 0):

You can the use flexbox on the wrapper elements which, really, should be block level and not a `span`s.

```css
#login {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
#login div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<form id="login">
  <legend>Login</legend>

  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Username">
    <input type="password" value="Password">
  </div>

  <div>

    <input type="checkbox">Remember
    <a href="./login/vergeten.html">Forgot?</a>
    <a href="./login/Registreer.html">Register</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this to align your button to the right end.

```
<input id = "login_button" type="submit" value="Login">
```

and in css add

```
#login_button{
  float:right;
}
```

You can use twitter-bootstrap-3 which will help you a lot. Take a look into it.

Comment: Not proper because only button is floating to right now, not the entire content.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But if he is looking for an easy way to do that and also if the project requires a lot more things like this then he is better off using libraries which will surely make the job easy.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is, add one more span and add `float:right` to it.

take a look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/adityap708/sedLvLp2/

```
<form id="login">
  <legend>Login</legend>
  <span>
    <input type="text" value="Username">
    <input type="password" value="Password"><br>
    <span style="float:right;">
    <input type="checkbox">Remember
    <a href="./login/vergeten.html">Forgot?</a>
    <a href="./login/Registreer.html">Register</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </span>
  </span>
</form>

#login {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```